# navigation drawer activity's interface jumps

Tags: xml, android-studio

There are both the interface and the navigation bar, and the link between the navigation bar and the interface is realized, and the navigation bar is clicked to jump to the interface.

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/dengluzhuce"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_login_registration"
            app:destination="@id/login_registration" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_appreciation_of_poetry2"
            app:destination="@id/appreciation_of_poetry" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_poetry_details2"
            app:destination="@id/poetry_details" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_poetry_search"
            app:destination="@id/poetry_search" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_category_browsing"
            app:destination="@id/category_browsing" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_one_sentence_a_day"
            app:destination="@id/one_sentence_a_day" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_learning_record"
            app:destination="@id/learning_record" />
<!--        <action-->
<!--            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_personal_center"-->
<!--            app:destination="@id/personal_center" />-->

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/login_registration"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.login_registration"
        android:label="fragment_login_registration"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login_registration" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/appreciation_of_poetry"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.appreciation_of_poetry"
        android:label="fragment_appreciation_of_poetry"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_appreciation_of_poetry" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/poetry_details"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.poetry_details"
        android:label="fragment_poetry_details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_poetry_details" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/poetry_search"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.poetry_search"
        android:label="fragment_poetry_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_poetry_search" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/category_browsing"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.category_browsing"
        android:label="fragment_category_browsing"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category_browsing" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/one_sentence_a_day"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.one_sentence_a_day"
        android:label="fragment_one_sentence_a_day"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_one_sentence_a_day" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/learning_record"
        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.learning_record"
        android:label="fragment_learning_record"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_learning_record" />

<!--    <fragment-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/personal_center"-->
<!--        android:name="android.example.setthestorm.personal_center"-->
<!--        android:label="fragment_personal_center"-->
<!--        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_personal_center" />-->


</navigation>
```

There are both the interface and the navigation bar, and the link between the navigation bar and the interface is realized, and the navigation bar is clicked to jump to the interface.

MainActivity

```
package android.example.setthestorm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.login_registration,R.id.appreciation_of_poetry,R.id.poetry_details,R.id.poetry_search,R.id.category_browsing,R.id.one_sentence_a_day,R.id.learning_record)  //,R.id.personal_center
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }


}
```